# How match system time with access database time?

Tags: database, vb.net, compare

I am creating an app in VB.NET that will play a song on user given time. User store song location and play time in ms-access database. when system time match with database time the song will play automatically. I've tried this with given below code but this is not working.

```html
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e
As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Call Play(Format(Now, "Long Time"))
    End Sub

    Sub Play(ByVal tm As String)
        Dim ConnectionString As String

        ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\VideoPlay.accdb;"

        Dim AccessConnection As New
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        AccessConnection.Open()

        Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT *
FROM VideoPlay", AccessConnection)

        Dim ds As New DataSet

        da.Fill(ds, "VideoPlay")

        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = ds.Tables("VideoPlay")

        Dim x As Integer

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For x = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                If tm = dt.Rows(x).Item("TM") Then
                    MsgBox("yes")
                End If
            Next
        End If

        AccessConnection.Close()
        da.Dispose()
        ds.Dispose()
        dt.Dispose()
        AccessConnection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can any one tell me what is wrong in my code or any other way to compare system time with database time.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your database table look like?

Comment: table has three fields 1- id, 2-songpath, 3-time